# default value for arg in Python function

Tags: python

case 1：

```
def good_append(new_item, a_list=None):
    if a_list is None:
        a_list = []
    a_list.append(new_item)
    print a_list, id(a_list)
    return a_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    one = good_append("one")
    two = good_append("two")
```

output:

```
['one'] 45267144
['two'] 45506312
```

case 2:

```
def good_append(new_item, a_list=None):
    if a_list is None:
        a_list = []
    a_list.append(new_item)
    print a_list, id(a_list)
```

output:

```
['one'] 44611784
['two'] 44611784
```

why get the same `id` in case 2

Comment: `id` values aren't guaranteed to be unique. They're only guaranteed not to be equal for objects alive at the same time.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct functions? I get different IDs in both (on Python 3, though).

Comment: @kazemakase yes, i'm sure